# List all Audiences in a site (in Console App)

Tags: user-profile-service, audience-targeting, audiences

I'm in the beginning of creating a custom web part that allows users to add themselves to Audiences and I'm first trying to get a feel for the API, by trying to simply list all Audiences I have on my site:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
                {
                    var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                    var audManager = new AudienceManager(context);

                    AudienceCollection audCollection = audManager.Audiences;

                    foreach (Audience audience in audCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(audience.AudienceName);
                    }
                }                                    
            });
        }
        catch(AudienceExecutionException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + "\n\n");
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I can connect to the site but keep receiving the following error:

```
AudienceExecutionException was unhandled by user code
Retrieving overall status encountered an error. 
Error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that since `Audiences` are tied into the `UserProfile` service, you need to add yourself as `Full Control` to either the `Administrators` or `Permissions` tab for the `User Profile Service Application`. I added myself to both -- not sure which one did the trick though I'm inclined to say it's the `Permissions` tab that did the trick.